# Tomcat running but not opening any ports and don't log anything

Tags: tomcat, vps

I have installed tomcat6 on Debian and it was running properly after installation from apt-get, but not after restart.

I launch by `/etc/init.d/tomcat6 start` (or restart), but netstat do not show opened port 8080 as configured.

`/ect/init.d/tomcat6 status` gives `Tomcat servlet engine is running with pid 1138.`

In `/var/log/tomcat6/` three log files are created (localhost*.log, catalina*.log and catalina.out, all empty.

I see nothing about tomcat in syslog.
After restart it was binding to IPv6 so I added JAVA_OPTS to `/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/catalina.sh`:

`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses`

Environment is VPS, 80MB free memory + 256MB swap, so added another opts from another question in SO:
`-XX:MaxPermSize=64m -Xms16M -Xmx64m`

But nothing helps, nothings is logged. How to find the problem ?

**no other services are binded to that port, and firawall isn't the cause because it was running after fresh install (and reinstall also, but always broken after restart)**

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat does not output errors or information to the system syslog.

Try looking for the catalina.out file and checking that for messages.

Comment: As i said, unfortunatellty nothing is logged, but problem is solved now

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. It seems that this issue is not about tomcat only, but anything related to java on VPS with **one virtual core**

Also, not only java execution but java compiler too. When compiling java, sometimes (randomly) i have a error reported from .cpp file (java source?) about lock/unlock function failed, related to multithreading.

**After requesting VPS support to divide my one virtual 1Ghz CPU to two cores with 0.5Ghz each, tomcat runs without problems**